# How to install numpy to Python 3.5?

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I'm attempting to install numpy on python3.5 via :

```
python3.5 -m pip install numpy
```

but receive error :

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.5: No module named pip
```

Same error for pip3 :

```
python3.5 -m pip3 install numpy
/usr/local/bin/python3.5: No module named pip3
```

Reason I'm attempting to install numpy this way is pip3 is pointing to a 3.4 `dist-packages` dir :

```
pip3 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Cleaning up..
```

How to install numpy to Python 3.5 ?

Update:

I decided to use docker in order to install on a clean ubuntu14.04 environment and it worked out of box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although using virtual environment is advisable in many use-cases, it is not strictly required. You can have a system `python3.5` and a `pip` installation associated with it.

Note that [Python 3.5 is now end-of-life](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3510/) and pip has now [dropped support](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id1). The final version of pip supporting Python 3.5 was 20.3.4 (Jan 2021).

1. Download this file: [`pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/79/8a850fe3496446ff0d584327ae44e7500daf6764ca1a382d2d02789accf7/pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl)
2. Bootstrap a pip installation using the wheel file: `sudo python3.5 pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
3. Install numpy with `python3.5 -m pip install --user numpy`

Comment: "This script does not work on Python 3.5. The minimum supported Python version is Python 3.6... 03.2021

Comment: @Hektor  Pip has recently dropped support for Python 3.5, so their get-pip script has stopped working. Thanks for the heads-up. I've updated this answer with an approach that doesn't rely on the script, it should continue to work with 3.5.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly recommend using a virtual environment and in the case of the scientific Python stack, I further recommend using [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It will save you loads of headaches in the future.

1. Download anaconda for Python3.5.
2. Create an environment.
3. Activate it.
4. `conda install numpy`.

Step 2 looks like this:

```
conda create --name env_name numpy
```

Step 3 looks like this:

```
source activate env_name
```

Step 4 looks like this:

```
conda install numpy
```

Now, anytime you want to use `numpy` or any other dependency in your environment, you just do `source activate env_name`.

To deactivate, do:

```
source deactivate
```